Как сделать, чтобы переменная из начала кода меняла значения на значение переменной из конца кода?
В начале кода я указываю переменную weapon = "sword" но в конце кода после определенных манипуляций переменная может принять значение "katana", Как сделать чтобы после того как переменная в конце кода поменяла свое значение переменная в начале кода сменила значение тоже, при условии что код зациклен
вот код для примера
while True:
  weapon = "sword"  #это верхнее значение
  print(weapon)
  change = input("whould you like to change current weapon")
  if change == "yes":
    weapon = "katana"
    #как сделать чтобы верхнее значение weapon тоже было ровно "katana" а не "sword" и при повторении уже выдавало katana
    print(weapon)


Вам просто нужно определить переменную weapon вне цикла.
Код:
weapon = "sword"

while True:
    print(weapon)
    change = input("whould you like to change current weapon")
    if change == "yes":
        weapon = "katana"
        print(weapon)

